# Can you treat anchors on a page as separate URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, mod-rewrite, anchor

Is it possible to have an anchor on a page, say, `index.html#section1` to be treated as a separate URL such as `/section1/` instead?

I am looking for something similar to what the Forbes website does on [this page](http://www.forbes.com/sites/samanthasharf/2014/10/22/international-worry-causes-market-pause-but-many-assume-its-only-temporary/). If you scroll down, another article loads and then the URL changes to that article's. How do they do it? Seems to be javascript but wouldn't you need something like mod_rewrite to create links like that?

Comment: JavaScript's History API can change the URL like that, and mod_rewrite would make sense of it if needed.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Correct, but I think that needs a polyfill if it is supposed to work in every browser

Comment: @TimSeguine https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ history.js to the rescue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first questinon, yes you need to just write rules in htaccess file if using apache, and allow mod_rewrite in your configuration files.

If you are looking to do something similar to Forbes website whit scrolling past anchor -> changing URL, you will have to not only write rules with mod_rewrite, but you will need to use JavaScript to determine when a user has scrolled passed the anchor and to change the url in adress bar. There are several jQuery plugins that will do the magic like http://janpaepke.github.io/ScrollMagic/ what I like to use.